# É possível fazer autenticação com angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

É possível fazer autenticação com Angular e recuperar o usuário logado?
Se possível qual a melhor prática de fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, porém vou aplicar uma resposta que utilizo.

faço autenticação de um usuário com o servidor, utilizando o serviço http, e caso a autenticação do lado do server seja positiva, devolvo um objeto de usuário com as informações que são necessárias para guardar na WEB.
para guardar essas informação na WEB, eu utilizo o SessionStorage, também poderia salvar no LocalStorage, isso vai da sua necessidade.

segue exemplo abaixo p/ incluir o mesmo no sessionStorage.

```
$http.post('url', objeto).then(function(retornoSucesso) {

    sessionStorage.setItem('userLogado', retornoSucesso.data) //objeto de usuário que utilizo.
});
```

Comment: Uma dúvida, como recuperar o usuário logado(Objeto) da sessão?

Comment: sessionStorage.getItem('userLogado') @Techies